# What can I do to get a stable bias on this current sink?

Tags: npn, current-sink, ramp-generator

I am still working on trying to get a stable 60 Hz ramp generator with a down-slope, and I am trying to do it from first principles and as simple as possible to understand fully what I'm doing.

I got myself 2N7000 MOSFETs and found they are perfect to drive high currents fast with TTL input on the gate. Nice way to discharge, or charge the capacitor rapidly. So I combined that MOSFET as a rapid charger with a NPN current sink to slowly discharge the capacitor.

[image]

My problem is this only works in theory, because in practice the biasing of the base with the R2 = 10k and R3 = 1k is incredibly fickle. If I use R3 = 1.1k or R3 = 0.9k the behavior is vastly different. So I know already that I won't get a stable ramp in practice, and I am stuck on this for weeks now. I have a perfectly fine 150 kHz ramp, smooth and stable. But the 60 Hz ramp I cannot get clean for the life of me.

I noticed in this simulation that I need that base to be at about 0.5 V, so it's just too little to do with a diode. If it could do with 0.7 V, then I could replace the 1k with a diode and be more stable I think. But I need 0.5V. What can I do?

I also noticed that the R1 and R4 and also the C1 don't really help me all too much with the tweaking. And I don't want to make C1 much bigger in order to cut down on the charge time, I need that to complete in 6 microseconds, but ideally less.

How about this here, can't quite find my simple standard diodes in the LTspice repertoire but I grabbed the switching diode with the lowest voltage as one that should probably do it.

[image]

This approach looks like it is more graceful given the tolerance on R2 and R3 variations, but I am a bit surprised by these very high values of 5 and 2 mega-ohm. Does this make sense at all?

The simulation looks nice, and with 630 mA peak on the capacitor charge, it looks practically doable.

[image]

Did I just answer my own question again? In this second schematic, if I vary those resistor values, I still get the ramp fairly stable. So I suppose I will try this. But comments or better ideas are much appreciated.

Notably I tried to use a JFET as a current sink but there I had an even bigger problem biasing the gate. So I gave up.

PS: yes I know I throw in a 100 nF bypass capacitor also so that I can serve the momentary 630 mA current draw with ease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, but op-amp circuits make a lot more sense at 60Hz. It will sink a fairly constant current for capacitor voltage 1.5V or more.

Also it would be better to use a P-channel MOSFET to charge the capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feapBG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, interesting, a current mirror, right? What would be a "matching" p-channel MOSFET to the 2N7000 (through hole TO92 package)? Ubiquitous, hope I can get it where I am (no access to Mouser or Jameco).

Comment: You can use a BSS84 SOT-23 with a breakout board.

Comment: It does work nicely with this current mirror, smoothly controllable with R3 as a trim-pot of 2-3 mega-ohm.

Comment: Very nice. You might consider flipping the current source to the high-side, using a couple of PNP's (2N3906). Sawtooth then rises instead of falls. An N-ch MOSfet, or even a NPN transistor can serve as the "discharge-to-ground" device for the 10nf capacitor. It is a bit easier to drive on/off with a ground-referenced pulse generator.

Comment: Hi again Spehro Pefhany, you say op-amp circuit would make more sense at 60 Hz. I am desperate to find ANY down-ramp circuit that doesn't create so much fuzz. Yes, I'm on a breadboard and yes my 5V power supply is fairly clean, hardly any ripples. I also use +/- 12 V, which is also fairly clean. Anything that would make sharply defined ramps, I'd welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the previous one, only the two transistors are in one case.
[image: nulla]

[image: egy]

The PMOS version:
[image: pmos]

The timing is unchanged, the amplitude of the sweep is 5V.

Comment: Thanks! I see, interesting, a current mirror, right? I see how you used a PNP BJT to charge the cap, in my experience the ability to sink current of my input signal VG1 in your schematics is a TTL device in my application, that ability to sink current is too low, so the BJT doesn't charge fast enough. I could use a Darlington pair if need be, but what would be a very common p-channel MOSFET in through hole format, "matching" the 2N7000 that I could hopefully get where I am?

Comment: I will also show the PMOS version in the edit.

Comment: What's the purpose of the R1 and R2 in the PMOS version? You are biasing the gate somehow with it. Is it necessary? Doesn't the 330 ohm resistor slow things down?

Comment: R1 only closes the FET even if no control is connected. R2 limits the current, which could be too large for the control due to the FET input capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

I love Sphero Pefhany's current mirror approach. And I'm just adding a me-too answer here to show how nicely it works including the p-channel MOSFET to get that full range of +5V to 0V for this ramp.

[image]

I guess I will see how realistic I can get that gate current to work, since that inverter A1 is a TTL device and in LTspice these logic gates are idealized, unreal high current devices. In the following the green is the Y-out ramp, at the time of rapid charge (rising edge), the red is the controlling digital after the inverter, and blue is the gate current. I guess I shouldn't worry, that gate current a minuscule peak relating to the very small gate capacitance, I guess.

[image]

but otherwise a beautifully controllable device with a 2 mega-ohm trimpot at R4.

Here is the simulation showing the full ramp in blue, the timing pulse V2 in red, and the current mirroring emitter currents of Q1 and Q2 in grey and green.

[image]

I am very happy about having learned the application of a current mirror to control a current sink better than a simple voltage divider approach on a single NPN.

Later I will show real scope traces still to close this matter out.

PS: I am still interested in radically different approaches.

**UPDATE**: Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I end up with fuzz on the ramp that makes it unusable.

[image]

It's the same problem I had with another attempt at a positive ramp and then inverted with Op Amps. Still, I get this fuzz which ends up making it unusable. Here, this should be pixels:

[image]

and this fuzz doesn't come when I use digital ramps with hand-made R-2R DACs.